# JQuery: .on handlers not attaching to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a comment system right now. When the page loads, there is a box to create a new comment, as well as a number of comments with reply buttons. The reply buttons when clicked clone and append the comment text box like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.reply-button')
    .one('click', function(){
      var parent_id = $(this).parent('.comment').attr('id')
      var parent_id_field = "<input value='" + parent_id + "' type='hidden' name='comment[parent_id]'' id='comment_parent_id'>"
      $(this).replaceWith($('#master-comment-form').clone().attr('id', "reply-div-" + parent_id))
      $('#' + "reply-div-" + parent_id).find('.field').append(parent_id_field)
    });
```

When the box is filled and the form is submitted, I run this script to append the comment baed on the response of the AJAX call.

```
jQuery(function () {
    //target comment-form from comment form partial
    $(".comment-form-div")
        .on("ajax:beforeSend", function (evt, xhr, settings) {
            console.log("Ajax request sent")
            return $(this).find('text_area')
                .addClass('uneditable-input')
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        })
        .on("ajax:success", function (evt, data, status, xhr) {
            console.log("Ajax request successful")

            $(this).find('text_area')
                .removeClass('uneditable-input')
                .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
                .val('');
            return $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('slow');
        });
});
```

The issue is that the JQuery to append the comment only works on the original reply box. The new reply boxes -- the ones generated from the .clone on the comments -- do not appear to have a handler attached to them and while the form still submits, the JQuery .on for the AJAX call is never run.

Comment: You can bind the events this way: `$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', '.comment-form-div', function () { ... }).on('ajax:success', function () { ... });`. The second argument from `on` method in this case is a selector. I'm not sure if it'll work with ajax events, but you can give it a try. Refer to the following link for more information: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be one of the situations where it's appropriate to use delegated event handling

```
$(document).on('ajax:beforeSend', '.comment-form-div', function (evt, data)
{
   //do something
});
```

The event will be bound to the document but will check to see if it's being applied to the child selector, the second argument of `.on`

Comment: That worked excellently. Thank you. But I'm having one more issue. When I create a new comment, the first block of code appends it. But the reply button on that new comment doesn't work. I tried using a delegated event handler on it but the problem is that using the .one() method will now only let me create one reply box in the whole document. Any way to allow .one on each individual element, even new elements?

Comment: For reference it looks like: 
`
  $(document)
    .one('click', '.reply-button', function(){
     //stuff
    }
`

Comment: That "one" event is applying to the entire handler- the entire document.click. Instead of using `one`, I would use `on` and set a data attribute on the element, e.g. `$(this).data('activated', true')` and then have an if statement to check if the element has been activated `if ($(this).data('activated')) { //do event handler }`

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you.